# Pandas Dataframe groupby Display

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have a DataFrame like following.

```
      A      B
0    text1   200
1    text2   200
2    text1   400
3    text2   500
4    text1   300
5    text1   600
6    text2   300
```

I want to print following output

```
     A             B
0    text1,text2   200
2    text1         400
3    text2         500
4    text1,text2   300
5    text1         600
```

There is no order,I just want to take text labels of column "A" for matching values in column "B". This has to be done with `df.groupby` as I know. Any way no success with my efforts yet. Hope you get my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can *nearly* do this with a [plain ol' `sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups):

```
In [11]: df.groupby('B').sum()
Out[11]:
              A
B
200  text1text2
300  text1text2
400       text1
500       text2
600       text1
```

You could use an [aggregate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation) with a [`join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
In [12]: df.groupby('B').agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x.values))
Out[12]:
                A
B
200  text1, text2
300  text1, text2
400         text1
500         text2
600         text1
```

Comment: As always your answers are short sweet and elegant..:) Thanks worked perfectly.

Comment: Also, *nearly* a transform: `df.groupby('B').transform(', '.join)` (which would have been more elegant)... Glad it helped!